# Quisiera que el textbox no me genere una carpeta cuando genero un pdf

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenos dias mi pregunta es el siguiente

```
string archivo = txtExpediente.Text + "-" + txtNumero+ ".pdf";
```

el problema que tengo es que el expediente se genera con / y eso hace que se me genere una carpeta
y lo que quiero lograr es que se forme la imagen nomas

Comment: Haz un `Replace` del caracter `/`

Comment: Me podrias mostrar como seria ? yo quiero que remplace el / por el -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera de solucionar tu problema es usar [`string.Replace(string, string)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1), este método simplemente reemplazará todas las ocurrencias del primer parámetro en el `string`, por el `string` del segundo parámetro.

Por lo que tendrías que hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
var expedienteClean = txtExpediente.Text.Replace("/", "");
var archivo = expedienteClean + "-" + txtNumero + ".pdf";
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda y la explicacion

Comment: @Interfile ahora marca la respuesta como aceptada, solo el creador de la pregunta puede hacerlo (click en el check verde del costado de la respuesta), con esto ayudarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio :D